# I want to separate certain filter values, i know I made a mistake in the code, but where?

Tags: magento-1.7

i know I made a mistake in the code, but where?

```
    <?php $attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
        <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute'): ?>
            <?php $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute'; ?>
            <?php $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>

               <?php if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1023'): ?>
               <?php echo ('<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>') ?>

               <?php else: ?>
               <?php if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1024'): ?>
               <?php echo ('<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>') ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATED**

With this code work perfect, but i need to customize it.

```
    <?php $attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute') {
            $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute';
            $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
            foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {

               if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1023') {
               echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>';
               }
               else
               if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1024') {
               echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>';
               }

            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you close `if` in wrong way in your code.!

Comment: If you open a construct, close it again and in the right order.  Indent your code correctly and it will soon become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fix the indentation in your code and use a IDE that will highlight open and close tag

```
<?php $attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes(); ?>
<?php $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute'; ?>
<?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'j_razdel'): ?>
        <?php $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init(); ?>
        <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>

           <?php if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1023'): ?>
                <?php echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>'; ?>
           <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1024'): ?>
                    <?php echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>   

        <?php endforeach;  ?> 

    <?php endif; ?>         
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You could also use `elseif($option->getValue() == '1025,1024'):` see

```
<?php $attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes(); ?>
<?php $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute'; ?>
<?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'j_razdel'): ?>
        <?php $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init(); ?>
        <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>

           <?php if ($option->getValue() == '1025,1023'): ?>
                <?php echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>'; ?>
           <?php elseif($option->getValue() == '1025,1024'): ?>
               <?php echo '<a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a>'; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>   

        <?php endforeach;  ?> 

    <?php endif; ?>         
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your current code

```
<?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute'): ?>
       ...
        <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>
        .....
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute'): ?>
      ...
         <?php foreach($result->getItems() as $option): ?>
           .....
         <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thnx, i tried it, but your option not work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH on line 15

Comment: Take a look at my update

Comment: What ERROR are you getting in magento. Check your server log

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change one important thing! Now everything works fine. Really big thnx!

Comment: Also look at my update